# jQuery conflicts with mouseover event on navigation menu‮

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototype

I have a navigation menu in Magento which, on mouseover, shows subcategories.
There is also a countdown which uses a jQuery plugin.

If I remove the countdown the menu works fine, but if I add the countdown, the countdown works fine, but the menu won't show the categories anymore on mouseover.

The code for a menu item:

```
<div id="menu10" class="menu popup-menu level-2" onmouseover="wpShowMenuPopup(this, 'popup10');" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup10', 'menu10')">
<div class="parentMenu">
<a href="supertrash.html">
<span>SuperTrash</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="popup10" class="popup child-2" onmouseout="wpHideMenuPopup(this, event, 'popup10', 'menu10')">
<div class="block1">
<div class="column"><div class="itemMenu level1"><a class="itemMenuName level1" href="supertrash/supertrash-rokjes.html">Rokjes</a></div></div><div class="column"><div class="itemMenu level1"><a class="itemMenuName level1" href="supertrash/stschoenen.html">Schoenen</a></div></div>
<div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The javascript for a mouseover:

```
function wpShowMenuPopup(objMenu, popupId)
{
    objMenu = $(objMenu.id); var popup = $(popupId); if (!popup) return;
    popup.style.display = 'block';
    objMenu.addClassName('active');
    var popupWidth = CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_WIDTH;
    if (!popupWidth) popupWidth = popup.getWidth();
    var pos = wpPopupPos(objMenu, popupWidth);
    popup.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
    popup.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
    if (CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_WIDTH) popup.style.width = CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_WIDTH + 'px';
}
```

The jQuery plugin which is used for the countdown:

```
<!-- jquery framework from google api -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- google font-family, you can add whatever font suits you -->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Averia+Serif+Libre:300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- The stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="counter2/css/style2.css">

<!-- the countdown plugin -->
<script src="counter2/coffeetime/coffeetime.min.js"></script>
<!-- The countdown style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="counter2/coffeetime/ctstyle.css">
<script>

/* here u can set up different messages for the progress of the countdown
if no message is set for the current percent value, it takes the next message, bigger or equal to that percentage
*/
var message = new Array();
message[0] = "status: just started";
message[10] = "status: drinking a coffe";
message[20] = "status: just finished setting up the database";
message[30] = "status: brainstorming about the template";
message[50] = "status: choosing the color scheme";
message[80] = "status: thinking about the future";
message[90] = "status: nearly done";
message[100] = "status: finished";

$(document).ready(function() {

function callback() {
    alert("Sale is over");
}


$("#flipit").coffeetime({
                        /* COUNTDOWN SETTINGS */
                        message: message, // the message array with the array keys as percent values
                        startYear: 2012,
                        startMonth: 8,
                        startDay: 30,
                        endYear: 2012,
                        endMonth: 9,
                        endDay: 7,

                        callbackFinish : callback,
                            });

$(".flip-title-subheading").html(" we started on "+ window.startDate+ " and we`ll finish on "+ window.endDate);

});

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".flip-container").animate({
            "height" : 105 + "px"
        }, 1000, "swing");
    }, 1000);
});

</script>
```

I've tried several things:

- In the header there's also a (older (1.4.3)) version of jQuery included, tried replacing that with the 1.8.0 version, but then nothing worked
- I've tried removing the 1.8.0 version included in the countdown, the menu works properly then, but no countdown
- I've tried using jQuery.noConflict() for the countdown, the menu keeps working, but the countdown doesn't

I'm at a loss, I hope someone knows what I'm doing wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll tell you to try noConflict(), but you already tried. So, try change $ for jQuery, this garantee magento uses the right JS, cuz prototype uses $ too.
If don't work, look for 2 JS script doing the same thing on your page. And remove's one.

Comment: Wasn't exactly right, but you pointed me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the mouseover function as

```
jQuery.noConflict();

function wpShowMenuPopup(objMenu, popupId)
```

{

```
objMenu = jQuery(objMenu.id); var popup = jQuery(popupId); if (!popup) return;
popup.style.display = 'block';
objMenu.addClassName('active');
var popupWidth = CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_WIDTH;
if (!popupWidth) popupWidth = popup.getWidth();
var pos = wpPopupPos(objMenu, popupWidth);
popup.style.top = pos.top + 'px';
popup.style.left = pos.left + 'px';
if (CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_WIDTH) popup.style.width = CUSTOMMENU_POPUP_WIDTH + 'px';
```

}

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

It was the noConflict() after all.

Adding the following just before the countdown script

```
var $c = jQuery.noConflict();
```

And changing all `$` variables in the countdown to `$c` worked.

I was using the `$i` and `$j` variables for the noConflict (which were declared earlier on), but making a new one worked magic. Thanks all!